# Increase, decrease Value in Object - javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to increase value in the object after clicking on the button for "booked" of amount + 1, how to do this?

```
var hotel = {
  name : "King",
  rooms: 40,
  booked: 25,
  checkAvailability: function() {
    return this.rooms - this.booked;
  }
};

function decA(){
 hotel.booked[ this + 1 ];
}

var elName = document.getElementById("hotelname");
elName.textContent = hotel.name + hotel.rooms;

var elRooms = document.getElementById("demo");
elRooms.textContent = hotel.checkAvailability();
```

Comment: `hotel.booked[ this + 1 ]` does not do what you think it does – you can mutate hotel: `hotel.booked += 1` – or create a new hotel: `{ ...hotel, booked: hotel.booked + 1 }`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason this is not working is because the ***scope*** of the variable is only within the variable `hotel`, because is was ***defined*** within the variable `hotel`. You could define it *outside* the variable `hotel` (e.g. at the top of your document), then **use it** *within* the variable `hotel`. This should hopefully work.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function to get and set internal scope like:

```
var hotel = {
  name : "King",
  rooms: 40,
  booked: 25,
  checkAvailability: function() {
    return this.rooms - this.booked;
  },
  bookARoom: function () {
    return this.booked++;
  },
  getBookedRoom: function () {
    return this.booked;
  }
};
```

and you can call hotel.getBookedRoom() and hotel.bookARoom() to get and set internal scope